# Is this is a high quality question?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

just failed an audit. It was for this question:

[How to detect if mouse is clicked other than $(this) element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284158/how-to-detect-if-mouse-is-clicked-other-than-this-element)

I tried to add a comment explaining that the `$(this)` selector was always the element that had been clicked, because it was in the click handler.

I know it's a technicality, but it came across as if he was trying to add a "didn't click" handler or something. The comment in the code also confirms he was trying to handle "didn't click" as an event.

I wasn't going to vote it down or anything of course, I just wanted to clarify this wasn't the right approach for this problem, and instead that you needed to select the other elements in the click handler (css solutions aside) - just purely to help with the understanding.

No big deal, but long story short - is this really a high quality question? Personally I'd have lumped it firmly in "it's OK".

---

*EDIT:*

I don't really understand how the possible duplicate applies - they're both talking about a similar thing, but I'm specifically referring to this question, not that one. That one also seems to be more about moving or criticising a question, where I was more trying to clarify the approach to the problem.

Comment: _“I tried to add a comment explaining that the `$(this)` selector was always the element that had been clicked, because it was in the click handler.”_ I think the asker knows that. The point was to change the element back when it _wasn’t_ `$(this)` anymore. _“How do I detect if mouse is clicked other than `$(this)` element.”_ doesn’t sound like an attempt to bind a `didntclick` listener.

Comment: I got that impression partially because the `//if clicked other than the block do stuff` comment was outside the click handler, when of course the time to change the other elements back is when you do click on something else.

Comment: SE hasn't yet properly implemented the mind-reader interface, so your intent when commenting on an audit is immaterial.

Comment: The problem I have with this one isn't that I'm not allowed to comment on an audit question - it's that this question was deemed to be high quality in the first place. It should have been fairly easy to solve with a bit of research, as long as the poster asks the right questions, hence I think it's valid to add a comment clarifying the approach to the problem.